# Xerces-C XSModel port from Java

Tags: java, c++, xml, xsd, xerces

I am attempting to port some Java code utilizing Xerces v3.2.2 that loads a schema file, retrieves the XSModel* and parses it into some custom data structures.

**JAVA**

```
import org.apache.xerces.XSLoader;
import org.apache.xerces.XSModel;

XSImplementation xsLoader = null;
XSLoader xsLoader = null;
XSModel xsModel = null;

xsImpl = (XSImplmentation) domRegistry.getDOMImplementation("XS-Loader");
xsLoader = xsImpl.createXSLoader(null);
xsModel = xsLoader.loadURI("path-to-schema.xsd");
myDataStruct = new MyDataStruct(xsModel);
```

I have been unable to find anything in Xerces-c documentation that would yield similar results. As far as I can tell, I can access the `XSModel*` from the `xercesc::GrammarResolver*` through the `xercesc::AbstractDOMParser` but this would require me to derive from the parser as it is a protected function.

**CPP**

```
#include <xercesc/parsers/XercesDOMParser.hpp>

using namespace xercesc;

class MyDOMParser : public XercesDOMParser
{
public:
    using AbstractDOMParser::getGrammarResolver;
};    

int main()
{
    XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();

    MyDOMParser parser;
    parser.loadGrammar("path-to-schema.xsd", Grammar::GrammarType::SchemaGrammarType);
    auto resolver = parser.getGrammarResolver();
    auto xsModel = resolver->getXSModel();
    MyDataStruct myDataStruct{xsModel};
    return 0;
}
```

Is this the route I must go? Will this even work? Are there examples out in the wild that show a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution I attempted for **CPP** does appear to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish. By deriving from `XercesDOMParser` I am able to access the `GrammarResolver` and therefore the `XSModel`. The model seems to contain the data my data structure requires for parsing.

Comment: When using the above solution, the MSVC compiler complains "use of undefined type 'xercesc_3_2::GrammarResolver'". GrammarResolver.hpp must be included.